# Caesar Cipher strange repetition

Tags: python, encryption

OK so i am making a Caesar Cipher program that moves the letters along by +5.

This is my code:

```
alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

phrase = input("Please enter a phrase without any punctuation")
phrase = str.upper(phrase)
phrase = phrase.replace(" ","")

for each in range(len(phrase)):
    letternum = alphabet.index(phrase[each])
    if letternum > 21:
        letternum = letternum+5-26
        phrase = phrase.replace(phrase[each],alphabet[letternum])

    else:
        letternum = letternum + 5
        phrase = phrase.replace(phrase[each],alphabet[letternum])

print("Your encrypted phrase is:",phrase)
```

This is my output:

```
Please enter a phrase without any punctuation: abcdefghijk
Your encrypted phrase is: PLMNOPLMNOP
```

Why does the program repeat the same letters even though i enter different ones? Also why is a not e and b not d etc? How do i fix this?

Comment: I think you have a logic problem when you do `replace`. For example, If you're scanning "AF", you do "replace A with F" and get "FF". Then you do "replace F with K" and get "KK".

Comment: The easiest way to do this is use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) `{start_char: end_char}`. Also, note that `phrase = str.upper(phrase)` can be `phrase = phrase.upper()` (in general, you can always write `Class.method(instance)` as `instance.method()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kevin, mentions, you are overwriting `phrase` so some characters will get encoded multiple times.

The solution is to build up the answer in a new variable:

```
answer = ""
for each in range(len(phrase)):
    letternum = alphabet.index(phrase[each])
    if letternum > 21:
        letternum = letternum+5-26    
    else:
        letternum = letternum + 5
    answer += alphabet[letternum]

print "Your encrypted phrase is:", answer
```

This could be written more succinctly using the `%` operator:

```
for each in range (len(phrase)):
  letternum = alphabet.index(phrase[each])
  answer += alphabet[ (letternum + 5) % 26 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you a simpler way of writing your Caesar cipher program:

```
import string

def main():
    key = 5
    table = str.maketrans(string.ascii_letters,
                          string.ascii_lowercase[key:] +
                          string.ascii_lowercase[:key] +
                          string.ascii_uppercase[key:] +
                          string.ascii_uppercase[:key])
    plaintext = input('Please enter a phrase: ')
    ciphertext = plaintext.translate(table)
    print('Your encrypted phrase is:', ciphertext)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```